# В чем отличие res.locals от объекта отправляемого в метод res.render('...', {})?

Tags: node.js, express

Всем доброго времени суток. В чем отличие res.locals от объекта отправляемого в метод res.render('...', {}) в ExpressJS? Никак не могу понять, записываю в res.locals данные - рендерятся нормально, в res.render - то же самое. Или эти объекты дублируют друг друга? В каких случаях что лучше использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[res.locals](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals) - это хранилище информации общей для всех обработчиков запроса. Хороший пример в документации - авторизация выполняется в отдельном обработчике и далее параметры авторизации (например, аккаунт) через `res.locals` становятся доступны в следующих обработчиках запроса.

`locals` в [res.render](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render) - это объект, атрибуты которого становятся локальными переменными во вьюхе. Хорошая практика - не передавать/не использовать `res.locals` или, используя, стараться разделять внутреннюю информацию и данные для подстановки в шаблон.

Comment: понял, благодарю!